# "No executable specified." Ubuntu SDK Unity8

Tags: unity, compiling, ubuntu-sdk, qt-creator, cmake

Was working last night, but today when I started up again, I could not run unity8 out of QtCreator/UbuntuSDK. After building and running, it just states:
"No executable specified."

FYI; This is a branch I imported from lp:unity8 into QtCreator. No edits have been done

Where and how do I specify the executable?

Comment: I'm just suffering from the same issue. I'll write a bug report.

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-touch-meta/+bug/1299441

Comment: At least I know I am not crazy; I have been asking ALL around IRC for ages, and no one has given me even as much as a clue what is going on.  Anyways, I went ahead and confirmed the bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

1. Go to **Tools > Options > Build & Run > Qt Versions**.
2. Check if there is a version mentioned there.
3. If not, select **Add...** and choose `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/qmake` and try to build again.

**Note:** Please adjust the above path according to your installation, especially `i386-linux-gnu`, which might be something like `amd64-linux-gnu` if you're on a 64-bit system.

Comment: probably `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/qmake` for 64 bit

Answer (score 1):

Your accepted answer didn't work for me. A workaround suggested here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-touch-meta/+bug/1299441 was to delete the CMakeLists.txt.user each time before starting qtcreator.

But updating qtcreator to version 3.1 worked for me.